# Does the series $ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\cos(na) \ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}} $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Does the series $ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\cos(na) \ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}} $ converge?

---

I have thought of using the Abel test but I am not sure if the sequence $ a_n = \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ is decreasing.

Here is what I tried:

$$a_{n + 1} - a_{n} = \frac{\ln(n + 1)}{\sqrt{n + 1}} - \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{\ln(n + 1)}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow 0.$$

Does it imply that the sequence $(a_n)$ is decreasing?

Comment: Decreasing is equivalent to $a_{n+1}-a_n<0$, so having a nonpositive limit isn't enough. Hint: use calculus to show that the function $\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt x}$ is eventually decreasing.

Comment: If you want to use Abel then you need to bound partial sums of  $\sum\cos{an}$. For $a=2\pi$ the series obviously diverges.

Comment: @markvs For $ a = 2 \pi $, we will have $ \sum \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$, and we will use the fact that $  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}  $, for $n$ large enough, am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use calculus:
$$f(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\implies f'(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}}}{x}=\frac{1-\ln(x)}{x\sqrt{x}}\leq 0 \,\, \forall x\in \left[e, +\infty\right)$$
So, $a_n$ is decreasing.